# Laggy OpenSSH on M1 Mac?

Tags: ssh, openssh, apple-m1

Typing can be very laggy when remote into other computers via OpenSSH from M1 Mac Book Air.
Both builtin Teminal.app and iTerm2 behave the same.

Usually it starts fine, but quickly becomes laggy. This is dangerous and has caused serious problems for me...

Current walkaround that works for me is to execute ssh forcing x84 arch like so

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh -c "ssh user@server..."
```

Is this a known issue or just happening to me somehow? Anyone else experiencing this as well? Is there better or more preferred way to fix this?

Thanks.